# Clarification on Closest Pair Algorithm: 6 or 7 Points in the Strip?

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, closest-points

I've been diving into the Closest Pair algorithm (to find the pair of points with the smallest distance among a given set of points in a two-dimensional space), and there seems to be a bit of confusion regarding the strip-checking step. In the literature, it's mentioned that we need to check the "7 points following each point p in array Y" within the strip around the dividing line. However, as I understand it, we're actually checking the 6 points including point p. Could someone clarify this for me? Is it 6 or 7 points? And if it's 7, how does that work geometrically? Thanks for shedding light on this!